# Unable to right click in firefox browser using selenium (java) automation

Tags: java, selenium

Only in firefox browser unable to right click in my selenium script. Below are the piece of code i have used

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.id("testing"));
action.contextClick(test).perform();//right click on job area
```

And below is the error is see while execute :

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

Comment: can someone help me to over come this issue

Comment: This is an open issue in selenium 3 with gecko driver. The selenium an webdriver developers already have this issue on their plate. you can track this  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4008. If you see the comments section in this issue, they have referenced the root cause for this.

Comment: Thanks you sameer !

Answer (score 1):

Try using this -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("testing"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
action.build().perform();
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate response but  while debugging, selenium unable to do action for the 3rd line "action.build().perform(); " and and it catches error as mentioned earlier

Comment: @ShivaRavi This Solution is perfect (+1) and should have worked for you. How ever I am too facing the same issue. But Issue [4008](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4008) issue is `Closed` now. Instead, as per Jim you can track [3808](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808) Thanks